# How can I programmatically retrieve the status of a webhook's last run?

Tags: azure-devops, webhooks, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a service which is called to via an Azure DevOps "Pull Request merge attempted" webhook.

Our users repos are likely to have a number of webhooks set up.

We're currently using `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client v16.147.0-preview` with PATs to communicate with Azure DevOps to retrieve info on our customers' repositories.

I am hoping to display something in our own UI which indicates the status of the last webhook call.

How can I check this status?

In the UI, I've used F12 developer tools to see the following:

1. Call to `https://{org}.visualstudio.com/_apis/hooks/subscriptionsQuery` with `publisherId = "tfs"` returns the list of webhook subscriptions. The subscription objects have no obvious property to key off to identify which webhook is part of my service.
2. Once the webhook subscription is identified, call into `https://{orgId}.visualstudio.com/_apis/hooks/notificationsQuery` with the webhook's subscription ID in the body to get the history of this subscription, including some metadata about the history status.
3. [Optional for more data] Given the history list of this subscription, find the latest executed one's ID, and call `https://{orgId}.visualstudio.com/_apis/hooks/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/notifications/{historyId}` to get the full data about the event.

Is there a way to call this via the client library we are using, with well defined types?

What is the best mechanism for determining which `subscriptionId` represents a subscription to our service (note - if it helps we can ask customer to set certain values in their configuraiton so that we can key off it)?